# Passing functions in python edited

Tags: python, function

```
from math import cos

def diff1(f, x): #approximates first derivative#
 h = 10**(-10)
 return (f(x+h) - f(x))/h

def newtonFunction(f,x):
 return x - f(x)/float(diff1(f,x))

y = cos
x0 = 3
epsilon = .001
print diff1(newtonFunction(y,x0), x0)
```

This is just a portion of the code, but I want to calculate diff1(f,x) where f is newtonFunction but uses the argument f passed to NewtonMinimum.  diff1 already takes f and x as an argument and I get an error saying it expects two arguments for newtonFunction.

Comment: `f` is `newtonFunction`? `newtonFunction` takes two parameters, not one, which is exactly what python is complaining about. And if python did accept it, it looks like infinite recursion to me.

Comment: I mean if i do diff1(newtonFunction, x) I get that error, or if i do diff1(newtonFunction(f,x),x) I get a different error.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the newtonFunction to the diff1 function because the parameters don't match up.  I think I must be missing obvious because it seems like it should be simple to pass the value of newtonFunction to diff1

Comment: Show us the actual code you actually tried and show us the result. Don't show us model code and then try to explain what's different.

Comment: ok i edited to what im trying to do. im trying to calculate diff1 with f being modified by newtonFunction first

Comment: this is the error Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 13, in <module>
    print diff1(newtonFunction(y,x0), x0)
  File "C:/Users/Alexboy/Documents/homework/2014 Spring/CompMath/hw6/testser.py", line 5, in diff1
    return (f(x+h) - f(x))/h
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
>>>

Comment: i realize the error but im not sure how to do the thing im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `f` is *not* `newtonFunction`, rather it's the value returned by `newtonFunction(y,x0)`. In this example that's a floating point number, hence the `'float' object not callable`.

If you want to pass a function as a parameter to another function, you need to use just its name:

```
diff1(newtonFunction, x0)
```

Note also that you will then have another problem: in `diff1` you're calling `f` with only one parameter, but `newtonFunction` takes two parameters.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing diff1(newtonFunction,x0) and i get an error for the two parameters thing

Answer (score 0):

In `diff1`, you are missing a `*` in `f(x+h)` and `f(x)` and in `newtonFunction`. You are also leaving `y` as a built-in function, so I assumed you wanted the `cos` of `x0`. Here is your edited code:

```
from math import cos

def diff1(f, x): #approximates first derivative#
 h = 10**(-10)
 return (f*(x+h) - f*(x))/h

def newtonFunction(f,x):
 return x - f*(x)/float(diff1(f,x))

y = cos
x0 = 3
epsilon = .001
print diff1(newtonFunction(y(x0),x0), x0)
```